# how to write data into hive table using spark remotely?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to hadoop world. I have installed spark 2.3.1 in my windows machine and installed cloudera inside vm in the same machine. i'm doing some data transformation in the form of dataframe using spark shell. Now i want to put this data to hive which is in cloudera using spark. i have googled and did the following steps.

1) Copied all the files in /etc/hive/conf and pasted to spark/conf in my windows.

2) In windows spark/conf open “hive-site.xml” and change property as below.

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://MyclouderaIP:9083</value>
  </property>
  <property>
```

3) Put host entry in window system C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

example : MyclouderaIP quickstart.cloudera

4) In cloudera vm open “/etc/hive/conf/hdfs-site.xml” and change the property like below

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
```

After finishing all the steps i am facing issues below.

```
scala> val Main = sc.textFile("D:\\Windows\\CompanyData.txt")

scala> Main.collect
```

Error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Pathname /D:/Windows/CompanyData.txt from hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/D:/Windows/CompanyData.txt is not a valid DFS filename.
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:197)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
  at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
```

i have removed "core-site.xml" from spark/conf and it can able to read textfile in windows . But it saprk is not able to communicate with cloudera while inserting a record .

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
scala> val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
scala> sqlContext.sql("insert into TestTable select 1")
```

Error:

```
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): 
File /user/hive/warehouse/TestTable/.hive-staging_hive_2018-10-17_00-03-48_369_2112774544260501723-1/-ext-10000/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20181017000351_0000_m_000000_0/part-00000-8fcba81b-8a51-48a6-9c47-ac5f1c9dafdb-c000 
could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  
There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

please can somebody help me .

Comment: Spark is on the VM, why make life difficult? An old version, so difficult. Get an HDP version or mapR if it still exists, or install yourself.